# Is there a way to swap columns in O(1) in Julia?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I picked up Julia to do some numerical analysis stuff and was trying to implement a full pivot LU decomposition (as in, trying to get an LU decomposition that is as stable as possible). I thought that the best way of doing so was finding the maximum value for each column and then resorting the columns in descending order of their maximum values.

Is there a way of avoiding swapping every element of two columns and instead doing something like changing two references/pointers?

Comment: Finding the pivots is an at least O(n²) operation, copying the matrix in the new order is also O(n²), so you will not gain much by doing the second step in a more efficient way.

Comment: Any time save is a time save

Comment: One possible answer here is to use a `Vector{Vector}` and store each column in it's own `Vector` which will allow swapping in `O(1)`. you'd have to benchmark if the copy back and forth was worth it.

Answer (score 5):

Just for "completeness", in case you actually want to swap columns in-place,

```
function swapcols!(X::AbstractMatrix, i::Integer, j::Integer)
    @inbounds for k = 1:size(X,1)
        X[k,i], X[k,j] = X[k,j], X[k,i]
    end
end
```

is simple and fast.

In fact, in an individual benchmark for small matrices this is even faster than the `view` approach mentioned in the other answers (views aren't always free):

```
julia> A = rand(1:10,4,4);

julia> @btime view($A, :, $([3,2,1,4]));
  31.919 ns (3 allocations: 112 bytes)

julia> @btime swapcols!($A, 1,3);
  8.107 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 4):

Following up on @longemen3000's answer, you can use views to swap columns. For example:

```
julia> A = reshape(1:12, 3, 4)
3×4 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 3, 4) with eltype Int64:
 1  4  7  10
 2  5  8  11
 3  6  9  12

julia> V = view(A, :, [3,2,4,1])
3×4 view(reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 3, 4), :, [3, 2, 4, 1]) with eltype Int64:
 7  4  10  1
 8  5  11  2
 9  6  12  3
```

That said, whether this is a good strategy depends on access patterns. If you'll use elements of `V` once or a few times, this `view` strategy is a good one. In contrast, if you access elements of `V` many times, you may be better off making a copy or moving values in-place, since that's a price you pay once whereas here you pay an indirection cost every time you access a value.

Answer (score 1):

in julia there is the @view macro, that allows you to create an array that is just a reference to another array, for example:

```
A = [1 2;3 4]
Aview = @view A[:,1] #view of the first column
Aview[1,1] = 10

julia> A
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 10  2
 3  4
```

with that said, when working with concrete number types (Float64,Int64,etc), julia uses contiguous blocks of memory with the direct representation of the number type. that is, a julia array of numbers is not an array of pointers were each element of an array is a pointer to a value. if the values of an array can be represented by a concrete binary representation (an array of structs, for example) then an array of pointers is used.

I'm not a computer science expert, but i observed that is better to have your data tightly packed that using a lot of pointers when doing number crunching.

Another different case is Sparse Arrays. the basic julia representation of an sparse array is an array of indices and an array of values. here you can simply swap the indices instead of copying the values

Comment: The idea is that all arithmetic is done on a column at a time, so if I have a pointer to the start of a column I just swap them around and I have no memory access problems, since operations are on columns and all columns are on contiguous memory

Comment: a matrix is just one big vector but with an associated shape. the index of a matrix is just a calculation of the offset where the value is located with a given shape. if you want to avoid the copy, you can store the indices in another array and return a view of the modified array with those indices. you save the copying at the cost of slower indexing later on

Comment: I could just work on the transpose matrix and treat rows as columns, but I wanted to know if just swapping columns was implemented

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something as Simple as this? Is there a computational load that this incurs, which I'm missing?

`````
julia> y = randn(4,4)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
  0.382866   1.95684     0.679879  -1.0213
 -0.644027   0.0286492   0.907008  -0.0116672
  1.13972   -1.66938     0.731684   0.39922
 -0.508178  -1.37069    -0.770984   0.058949

julia> temp1 = y[:,1]
4-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.3828664714656943
 -0.6440268000802201
  1.1397177369324478
 -0.5081782475166619

julia> temp2 = y[:,2]
4-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.9568436266456812
  0.0286492205511295
 -1.6693793024656984
 -1.3706938971653277

julia> y[:,1]=temp2
4-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.9568436266456812
  0.0286492205511295
 -1.6693793024656984
 -1.3706938971653277

julia> y[:,2]=temp1
4-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.3828664714656943
 -0.6440268000802201
  1.1397177369324478
 -0.5081782475166619````
`````